# Using sort function to sort parallel arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am supposed to write a sort function to sort inches of rainfall per month (entered by the user) into ascending order. The output is supposed to output the parallel arrays of the inches per month and the month it corresponds to. It is supposed to look something similar to "x inches of rain in (month)". X and (month) being the outputs for the parallel array. However, when I enter the inches of rain, there is no output.

I could be overlooking something but I feel it might be something simple like my call to the functions in the wrong order or I am not outputting the sorted arrays correctly. I have tried moving the sort and show functions around in the code and have also tried changing verbiage to no avail.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes
void getMonthlyRainfall(double[], string[], int);
double getTotal(const double[], int);
int getHighestAmount(const double[], int);
int getLowestAmount(const double[], int);
void dualSort(double[], string[], int);
void swap(double&, double&);
void swap(string&, string&);
void showOrder(const double[], string[], int);

int main()
{
    const int MONTHS = 12;
    string monthNames[MONTHS] = { "January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
"November", "December" };
    double rainfall[MONTHS], // Array
        total,
        average;
    int lowestIndex,
        highestIndex;

    //Get rainfall input from user
    getMonthlyRainfall(rainfall, monthNames, MONTHS);

        // Get the total amount of rain for the year
    total = getTotal(rainfall, MONTHS);

    // Get the average rainfall
    average = total / MONTHS;

    // Get the month with the lowest rainfall
    lowestIndex = getLowestAmount(rainfall, MONTHS);

    // Get the month with the highest rainfall
    highestIndex = getHighestAmount(rainfall, MONTHS);



    cout << "Total rainfall: " << total << endl;
    cout << "Average rainfall: " << average << endl;
    cout << "Least rainfall in: " << monthNames[lowestIndex] << endl;
    cout<< "Most rainfall in: "<< monthNames[highestIndex] << endl;

    // Sort the array.
    dualSort(rainfall, monthNames, MONTHS);

    // Display sorted numbers
    showOrder(rainfall, monthNames, MONTHS);



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the main portion of the code but the issue is specifically with the showOrder and dualSort functions. I will add those below.

```
//*************************************************
// This function sorts an array into ascending    *
// order.                                         *
//*************************************************

void dualSort(double rainfall[], string monthNames[], int size)
{
    int start, minIndex;
    double minValue;
    string tempId;

    for (start = 0; start < (size - 1); start++); 
    {
        minIndex = start;
        minValue = rainfall[start];
        tempId = monthNames[start];

        for (int index = start + 1; index < size; index++) 
        {
        if (rainfall[index] < minValue)
        {
            minValue = rainfall[index];
            tempId = monthNames[index];
            minIndex = index;
        }
        }

    swap(rainfall[minIndex], rainfall[start]);
    swap(monthNames[minIndex], monthNames[start]);
    }
}

//*************************************************
// The swap function swaps two int's in           *
// memory.                                        *
//*************************************************

void swap(double &a, double &b)
{
double temp;

temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
}

//***********************************************
// The swap function swaps two strings in       *
// memory.                                      *
//***********************************************

void swap(string &a, string &b)
{
string temp;

temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
}

//************************************************
// showOrder function displays sorted values     *
//************************************************

void showOrder(const string monthNames[],const double rainfall[], int 
num)
{
for (int index = 0; index < num; index++) 
{
    cout << rainfall[index] << "inches in " << monthNames[index] 
 << endl;
}
cout << endl;
}
```

I don't receive any compiler errors or messages and I am able to execute the rest of the program with no issues. The only issue is that when I expect there to be an output in ascending order, there is no output whatsoever.

EDIT--I probably should have been more clear about my code. The code for the selection sort is an algorithm directly from my textbook so it should be correct. Because this code is built on a code I previously wrote that requires a parallel array for rainfall and monthNames, I need to use parallel arrays in this instance to sort both string and double arrays. There is more code and more functions included in my code that I didn't post here because they are working correctly. One of those functions is for the parallel array to correlate rainfall and monthNames.

The debugger did not help too much unless I am using it incorrectly. Is there a different way of sorting a parallel array in ascending order because if there is, I can't find it online or in my book? At this point I am not even sure what the issue is. Even after going line by line and trying to work out the logic of it, I still don't see the issue. I am able to output the other functions I wrote correctly so unless I need to correlate the two arrays again in my dualSort function or I am missing a return statement somewhere, I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried simpler exercises first, like sorting a container of `int`?

Comment: Were you planning to do something with `tempId`?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Do you HAVE to use multiple arrays? This job is practically screaming for a single array of a structure.

Comment: You have no correlation between `monthNames` and `rainfall`. Where if you force `rainfall` to be entered in month-order, you can torment yourself by then attempting a dual-sort of both `monthNames` and `rainfall` in parallel, but unless that is a requirement for educational purposes, it is nonsensical. Any time you have to correlate between two disparate types like `string` and `double`, you should automatically think `struct` containing both `double` and `string` and then an array of them which can then be sorted on either member.

Comment: Aside: `std::swap` is a thing

Answer (score 0):

You can pair up references, and then sorting that will sort the arrays.

```
void dualSort(double rainfall[], string monthNames[], int size)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<double&, std::string&> > tied;
    tied.reserve(size);
    auto tie = [](double & rain, std::string & month){ return std::tie(rain, month); };
    std::transform(rainfall, rainfall + size, monthNames, std::back_inserter(tied), tie);
    std::sort(tied.begin(), tied.end());
}
```